# How to achieve the state of previous activity when we return back to it

Tags: android, android-intent, android-bitmap

I have an image view and two buttons(Gallery and Next) in an activity.When i press Gallery button,i am able to select an image from the gallery and assign the image as a bitmap to the image view.when i press Next button, i will go other activity and i am coming from this activity to the first activity by using intent.Then i did not find my image selected from the gallery in my first activity.i.e onCreatea() method of first activity is called.But i want to display the first activity with image when i return back to the first activity.Please help me.

This is my main activity

```
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.database.Cursor;
 import android.graphics.Bitmap;
 import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
 import android.net.Uri;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.provider.MediaStore;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.ImageView;
      import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity{
ImageView iv;
TextView tv;
int width=320,height=480;
  Button text,gallery;
private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    iv=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    text=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    gallery=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
    final Bitmap pf1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    Bitmap scaled=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(pf1, width, height, true);
    iv.setImageBitmap(scaled);
    //Intent i=getIntent();
    //String value=i.getStringExtra("mydata");
    //tv.setText(value);
    iv.setOnTouchListener(new myTouchListener());
    text.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),FrmActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
     gallery.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

            startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
        }
    });
    }
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

  if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data)  {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

            //ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
            //Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(pic.getWidth(), pic.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
          Bitmap  bitmap1=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
          Bitmap scaled=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap1, width, height, true);
        iv.setImageBitmap(scaled);
        iv.setOnTouchListener(new myTouchListener());


        }


    }
 public void onResume()
 {
     super.onResume();

 }
```

}

and my second activity is

```
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.content.Intent;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.widget.Button;
  import android.widget.EditText;

   public class FrmActivity extends Activity {

Button mButton;
EditText mEdit;


 @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_frm);
    mButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    mEdit   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
            //intent.putExtra("mydata",mEdit.getText().toString());
            startActivity(intent);


        }
    });
}
```

}

My main xml file is

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:scaleType="matrix" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_parenthetical="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="94dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="49dp"
    android:text="Text" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="Gallery" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and my second layout is

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_margin="5dp" >


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
    android:text="@string/input_lable"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="#0099FF" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
    android:background="#CCCCCC"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:background="#0099FF"
    android:text="@string/sub"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Override `onResume()` Method in your code. Provide some code how tdo you start your gallery with `startActivity` or with `startActivityForResult`

Comment: Because when you return back to your first activity `onResume` function is getting called so you have to manage the image inside this method.

Comment: What to override in onResume() method?

Comment: The image you have selected may be your file path or anything you got from your previous activity. How can i say anything as i don't have any idea what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Wat u gonna do in the activity , that u moving from firstactivity to next activity by clicking next button.

Comment: i have provided my code.please have a look.

Comment: I am taking string input by EditText to the first activity.But in the code,i enclosed the code in comments.If we remove the comments,code will be displayed on the first activity.I want to display the string input taken from second activity on the image of the first activity which is selected from gallery.But when i return back,there is no image selected from gallery,only text is displayed.I want to display the text on the image.